# Can someone tell me program flow of this python 2.7 script?

Tags: python

I'm a fledgling Python programmer, and I am studying a book on the subject from a well know series of books aimed at dummies.

Anyway, one of the examples from the book is below, and I need someone to tell me what is going on. I understand what the discrete parts of the script are doing, but the logical flow is confusing me (e.g. what objects are being created where and what is calling what).

I imaging this is pretty simple for an experienced programmer, but this is stumping me at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated. The script is below and all it does it output `'Red, Green, Blue + Yellow, Purple, Cyan = Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple, Cyan'`.

Thanks in advance. Script from the proceeding:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.Input = args

    def __add__(self,Other):
        Output = MyClass()
        Output.Input = self.Input + Other.Input
        return Output

    def __str__(self):
        Output = " "
        for Item in self.Input:
            Output += Item
            Output += " "
        return Output


Value1 = MyClass("Red", "Green", "Blue")
Value2 = MyClass("Yellow", "Purple", "Cyan")
Value3 = Values1 + Values2

print("{0}+{1}={2}".format(Value1,Value2,Value3))
```

Comment: I recommend using IDLE's Debugger. This way you can easily watch every step the interpreter is doing and learn about the control flow.
See: (https://inventwithpython.com/chapter7.html) for a tutorial.

Comment: Man that naming style is awful and against Python conventions. Please use camelCase for variables, and caps only for classes. To most programmers, `Output += Item` means "add the class `Item` to the class `Output`", whatever it means.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html) instead of a more fancy debugger but that's a matter of taste. It is the default python debugger that you can run to step through your code from the command line.

To use pdb in your script, import it at the point where you want to start stepping through, I think for this script the most interesting point would be in **add**():

```
    def __add__(self,Other):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        Output = MyClass()
        Output.Input = self.Input + Other.Input
        return Output
```

Now, if you run the script, execution will halt at the point where you have set the trace. You will be presented with a CLI, where you can step through the code and print out any information you find interesting.

```
> print(Output.input)
> s                   # for (s)tep
> print(Other.input)
```

Comment: Thanks this was really useful =)